# how to validation JSON as key from String param in power shell

Tags: powershell

I want to validate from PowerShell using this JSON

```
{
    "Customer":  {
                     "OnSubscription":  true,
                     "Name":  "John",
                     "Surname":  "Smith"
                 },
    "Data":  {
                 "Basket":  [
                                "apples",
                                "pears",
                                "oranges",
                                "strawberries"
                            ]
             }
}
```

here is my script

```
$json = Get-Content .\basket.json | ConvertFrom-Json
param(
[string[]]$param = "Customer"
)
Write-Host $param
if ($param -eq $json) {
Write-Host "Valid Customer Key"}
else
{
$message = "Invalid Customer Key" 
Write-Host $message
}
$output = ($json.$param.PSObject.Properties.Name | ForEach-Object {
    "$_={0}" -f $json.$param.$_
}) -join  "`n" 

$Path2 = ".\output\env"
$output | Out-File $Path2
```

The parameter create for checking the JSON, is there a valid customer key or not?
For example, input param ABC, but in JSON there is no ABC. So its showing message like "Invalid Customer Key". When condition is valid customer key, Its showing message like "Valid Customer Key"
but the result I always got "Invalid Customer Key"
Is something wrong with if condition?

Comment: The variable `$json` is confusing as after a `ConvertFrom-Json` it is simply a [`PSCustomObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject). Anyways, I recommend you the use the ' ConvertFrom-Json' [`-AsHashTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json#parameters) parameter and instead of: `if ($param -eq $json) {` do: `if ($json.ContainsKey($param)) {`.

Comment: -AsHashTable is not working

Comment: Statements as "*is not working*" won't help much. It is the [details](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (like actual/expected result, error messages, PowerShell version) that you need to add to your response and original question to eventually resolve *your* issue. Anyways, without `-AsHashTable`, you might check a property name like: `if ($Json.PSObject.Properties.Name -Eq $param) { ...` or install the latest version of [PowerShell Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-windows).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to clean your code up a bit and dont think with such complexity. Your Task is quite easy, I have mocked something up for you.

***loadMe.Json***

```
{
   "content":[
      {
         "Customer":{
            "OnSubscription":true,
            "Name":"John",
            "Surname":"Smith"
         },
         "Data":{
            "Basket":[
               "apples",
               "pears",
               "oranges",
               "strawberries"
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "Customer":{
            "OnSubscription":true,
            "Name":"John2",
            "Surname":"Smith"
         },
         "Data":{
            "Basket":[
               "apples",
               "pears",
               "oranges",
               "strawberries"
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "Customer":{
            "OnSubscription":true,
            "Name":"John3",
            "Surname":"Smith"
         },
         "Data":{
            "Basket":[
               "apples",
               "pears",
               "oranges",
               "strawberries"
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Step One - Get Content of Json into an Object

```
$myJson = Get-Content -Path (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot '\loadMe.json') | ConvertFrom-json
```

Step Two - Loop through content and match names

```
foreach($item in $myJson.content) {
  if($item.Customer.Name -eq $myOtherVariable) {
    ...
  }
}
```

The following code gives the wanted output, task accomplished

```
$myJson = Get-Content -Path (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot '\loadMe.json') | ConvertFrom-json

foreach($item in $myJson.content) {
  Write-Host $item.Customer.Name
}

Output -->
John
John2
John3
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but thats not what i'm looking for

Comment: @JovitaSutanto I see, your main issue is that you are comparing your $param to $json. Why would your param ever be the same as the entire file content ? Please do a Write-Host $param before your eq to see what i mean